# why is kernel process accounting not working?

Tags: kernel

I've turned process accounting on with `/usr/sbin/accton on` soon after boot and nothing is getting logged.

Default file is used: `/var/log/account/pacct`

All the commands to get output from this file are empty because the file is empty:

```
dump-acct /var/log/account/pacct
```

empty. ditto with `lastcomm` and `sa -a`. empty.

The 5.8 kernel has `CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT` turned on in `/boot/config*`

```
CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT=y
CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT_V3=y
```

What's missing?

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.2 with Mate desktop.

Comment: oh that still exists!

Comment: Works on my kernel. Can you do the following: Open two terminals. Become root in both (so we don't need to complicate our logs through later logins). In one, run `journalctl -xef` to see the latest system log messages as they happen. In the other, run `accton on`. You *should* be seeing `kernel: Process accounting resumed`.

Comment: (by the way, whatever you use this for, I bet there's better ways to find out what you're trying to find out, but that might be a separate topic)

Comment: If the filesystem having the process accounting file (/var/log/account/pacct) is nearly full, the kernel will suspend process accounting. So: `df -h /var/log/account/pacct` ?

Comment: hello @MarcusMüller, this was a helpful suggestion. I monitored the log with `journalctl -xef` and executed the `accton on` command and absolutely nothing showed up in the system log. Not even a newline. Nothing is registering. Is there a kernel module necessary for this functionality? I'm stumped.

Comment: @A.B, yes, this is possible, but there is plenty of space. 4.8Gb available. It's getting a little low on space so I' can make room, but I don't suspect this as the primary problem

Comment: the process accounting did work on a previous Ubuntu 20.04.2 installation but I started getting huge PID numbers after just a few days after boot. the original post causing this investigation into process accounting is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346963/why-is-pid-number-so-large-and-what-is-running-file-command. process accounting is not working on a *fresh* Ubuntu install. It's like there's a package missing

Comment: does `dmesg -Hwx` say something when you run `accton`? Maybe a kernel problem that doesn't end up in the systemd journal...

Comment: As long as 4.8Gb > 2% it's fine.

Comment: @A.B, you got it. I had 4.8Gb available but it was 1% in `df`. After reorganizing with `gparted` and crossing fingers a couple of times, all is well and now the accounting is working. it was a space issue.

Comment: @A.B, if you put your space suggestion and comments in as an answer I'll mark it as the answer and solved

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thank you for your help. those are good investigative suggestions. I had run out of tricks. now that process accounting is turned on I'm able to profile commands that get executed. This is an effort to determine why thousands of `file` (from `/usr/bin/file`) was being executed. both `clamav` and `rkhunter` said I had possible root kits or other malware. the other thread is the place for those suggestions. I have those process accounting dumps but have since reinstalled and am profiling the system by watching new PID counts per second to determine if the culprit was benign

Comment: that wouldn't be something I'd solve with process accounting, but with eBPF probes! That would've been pretty straightforward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accton` command's main role is to run a single syscall: [`acct(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/acct.2) as seen when stracing the command:

```
acct("/var/log/account/pacct")          = 0
```

The rest is handled by the kernel. As process accounting can generate a lot of logs [kernel periodically checks the percentage of free space in filesystem](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/kernel/acct.c?h=v5.10#n98) and suspends accounting until enough space appears. There is the [`kernel.acct`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.rst?h=v5.10#n31) sysctl for this. By default the triggers values are:

> ```
> 4 2 30
> ```
>
> That is, suspend accounting if free space drops below 2%; resume it if
> it increases to at least 4%; consider information about amount of free
> space valid for 30 seconds.

From OP's [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656018/why-is-kernel-process-accounting-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1234425_656018), it appears 4.8Gb were free, but these represented only 1% on the filesystem: kernel process accounting got suspended.

So this was a case of near filesystem full.

Accounting would resume within the next 30s once available space would reach ~ 9.6Gb ( ~ 4%). Or maybe just with a new syscall and > 2%?

It's still have been possible to halve the percent to 1% to get for OP's case accounting working until <2.4Gb but not much more can be done. It would be ill-advised to use 0%.

OP chose to increase the filesystem size to solve the problem.

Comment: About checking disk activity on a system still uncompromised (after which, any measurement from the system is to be considered unreliable), you can also check `blktrace` (and the wrapper `btrace`).

Comment: indeed, indeed, this solved the problem. it seems if space had been provided the kernel would have re-started process accounting on it's own. this is the most I've studied process accounting. I've searched quite well but nothing really like this answer ever became obvious. nice